# Method return 2 int values in java in loop

Tags: java

**I want to get two integer index in loop and send them to other method until user put -1 in index 1 ******

```
        public static int getIndex() {
        int index1, index2;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the first index in list(-1 to finish): ");
            index1= s.nextInt();
            if(index1==-1) {
                System.out.println("Program ends now...");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the second index in list: ");
            index2= s.nextInt();
        }while(true);
        return new Indexes(index1, index2);
    }
```

***The problem is how send the index to other method?
Thanks***

the other method:

```
public static String compare(ArrayList<Worker> workers, int index1, int index2 ) {
        if(workers.toArray()[index1].equals(workers.toArray()[index2])==true)
            return "EQUALS!";
        else
            return "NOT EQUALS";
    }
```

I call it via Main

```
        System.out.println(compare(list,index1, index2));
```

Comment: The method should be declared as `public static Indexes getIndex()` if you plan to return `Indexes` type.

Comment: You want to return two integers right? Why not return an array of integers with those two values?

Comment: ...and index2 needs to be initialized with some default value `int index2 = -1;`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true. But have they ever ran/executed their code?

Comment: Do you want the `compare(ArrayList, int, int)` method to be ran **once** or each time the `getIndex()` method runs?

Comment: 1. I change the name 2. I want the method Compare get 2 different indexes.   3. index2 no stop the program only when index1=-1   4.I want the method Compare run everytime the user put 2 indexes...

Comment: Yes. I know. Each time your `getIndex()` method is called, call `compare(Output)`. Because you are using a Scanner for input, your input will affect your code. How is my answer not helpful?

Comment: 1. ... you can rename your variables or methods to whatever you'd like. 2. Two different indexes... okay, you can input in such a way that makes that true. 3. index2 doesn't stop `getIndex()`. 4. Then you can call `compare(Output given);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question properly but
You can use Scanner class to scan through input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public static Indices getIndex() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index1, index2;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the first index in list(-1 to finish): ");
            index1 = s.nextInt();
            if(index1==-1) {
                System.out.println("Program ends now...");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the second index in list: ");
            index2=  = s.nextInt();
        }while(true);
         return new Indices(index1, index2);
    }
```

The best way to do this is to make your own custom class that has two fields int1, int2 and set them based on your index1, index2 variables.

```
class Indices{
  int point1, point2;
    public Indices(int p1, int p2){
      this.point1 = p1;
      this.point2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Then you can have two Indices and compare them how you'd like

```
  Indices i1 = getIndex();
  Indices i2 = getIndex();

  compare(i1,i2);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Running the method with given arguments

`methodYouAreCalling(getIndex());`

> Store in variables that the second method uses

```
indexX = Indexes.index1;
indexY = Indexes.index2;
```